# curl request to localhost takes a huge amount of time

Tags: php, curl

I need to make curl request via PHP to the same local virtualhost url. Its really simple. If I make it via Postman or in command line it takes miliseconds. But as I run it in PHP it is still loading without response. I make a log to file after each step so I can say the code stops after `Debugger::log(5555555555555)`.

This is the code:

```
public function sendRequest(string $url, array $data = null, $method = 'GET')
{
    $url = $this->apiUrl . $url;

    $ch = curl_init($url);
    $json = json_encode($data);

    Debugger::log(2222222222222);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);

    Debugger::log(2222222222222);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');

    if ($method == 'POST' or $method == 'PUT') {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json);
    }
    Debugger::log(33333333333);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PORT , 80);

    Debugger::log(44444444444);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
        'Authorization: Bearer ' . $this->apiKey,
        //'X-API-Token: v4yWSYY2Od7-iA6Vi3e8fRNWMkvii-eF',
        'Accept: application/json',
        'Content-Type: application/json',
        'Content-Length: ' . strlen($json)
    ]);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);

    Debugger::log(5555555555555);

    $output = curl_exec($ch);

    Debugger::log(6666666666666);

    if( curl_errno($ch) ) {
        Debugger::log(curl_error($ch), Debugger::EXCEPTION);
        throw new \Exception( curl_error($ch) );
    }

    Debugger::log(77777777777777);

    $header = curl_getinfo($ch);

    Debugger::log(88888888888888);

    curl_close($ch);

    $return = array("header" => $header, "output" => $output);

    return $return;
}
```

Comment: Few solutions you may try: 
1. Alternate between your IP, 'localhost' and '127.0.0.1', maybe it's a DNS issue of some kind. 
2. You didn't mention what OS you are on, try setting a proper loopback.
3. Use curl_setopt to setup specific options, Disalbe Nagles algorithm, CURLOPT_TCP_FASTOPEN and try to increase CURLOPT_BUFFERSIZE. 
4. Use Verbose on curl_setopt to try to debug the issue internally. 
5. you mentioned there's no reponse, check the debugger if it's trying to load something, or check if the message is valid (No internal errors). 
Good luck!

Comment: Address is not localhost its local wamp virtual host: http://lurity.crm.localhost/test/default OS is Windows 10 opt verbose is set to true. I dont know how to debugg it better. As I said console request or Postman request works fine.

Comment: Are you using SSL (Https) of some sort? 
It may be something in the implementation the php uses.

Comment: If you are on Windows, run a "netstat -an 5" before running the PHP script. Check if you can see the connection to localhost and which TCP state it shows. You set the destination port to 80 in your script via `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PORT, 80);` which is normally not necessary as the port will be taken from the URL.

Comment: @SimplyCode Thanks a lot. The problem was in non existing endpoint. I am sorry.

Comment: @SaschaM78 Thanks a lot. The problem was in non existing endpoint.